# How to extract first 10pages from each pdf files of a folder

Tags: command-line, pdf, batch, pdftk

I have 90 sub-folders in a folder. Each sub-folder contains pdf files. Total pdf files are nearly 2200. How can I extract page number 3 to 10 from all pdfs?

To extract the pages from one pdf, I am using the following command.

```
pdftk *.pdf cat 3-10 output 3-10.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *one liner* (split into 2 lines for ease of reading) was tested and works well on my system:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec bash -c \
'pdftk "$0" cat 3-10 output "${0%.pdf}_3-10.pdf"' {} \;
```

Simply open a Terminal window in the base folder (the one that contains all of the sub-folders) and copy and paste the entire one line command given above. It will:

1. Traverse all of the sub-folders and identify all the pdfs
2. Extract pages 3-10 from each (using your example command)
3. Give a *sensible* output filename: the original name with `_3-10` added

And this should neatly and economically accomplish your purpose...

**Variation:**

Optionally you could give a *different* output location to collect all of the altered pdf documents. For example you could create a folder called `~/extracted` and alter the commandline above to the following:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec bash -c \
'pdftk "$0" cat 3-10 output "~/extracted/${0%.pdf}_3-10.pdf"' {} \;
```

And thus all of the altered pdf files would appear in `~/extracted`.

Endless possibilities :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use qpdf as pdftk is not available on ubuntu bionic by default any more:

`find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec bash -c 'qpdf --empty --pages "$0" 3-10 -- "temp/${0%.pdf}_1.pdf"' {} \;`

This will put the new pdf's into temp folder.